# PPP: Modem hangup on IPCP negotiation

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ip, busybox, ppp

First of all, sorry for the question if it is obvious, I'm not very good at network configuration.

I'm currently trying to connect a Linux machine with Busybox through a modem to a cellular network (T-Mobile NL). After configuring `ppp` according to the [network parameters](https://service.t-mobile.nl/app/answers/detail/a_id/3043), `ppp` connects successfully to the modem, but when starting IPCP negotiation, the modem hangs up, without any indication of the error. The only thing I can imagine is that it is linked to IPCP negotiation, since it is the step of the connection during which the modem hangs up.

Here is my configuration:

**ppp options:**

```
/dev/modem_at0
lock
debug
logfile /var/log/ppplog
115200

linkname ppp0
defaultroute
replacedefaultroute

auth
user "tmobile"
password "tmobile"

crtscts
holdoff 3
persist

connect '/usr/sbin/chat -v -t 90 -f /etc/ppp/peers/gsm_chat'
disconnect "chat -- \d+++\d\c OK ath0 OK"

noipdefault
novj
novjccomp
noaccomp
nobsdcomp
novj
noccp

ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
ipcp-restart 15
ipcp-max-failure 10
ipcp-restart 10
maxfail 40
ipv6cp-restart 15
```

**Modem chat:** (`/etc/ppp/peers/gsm_chat`)

```
SAY "GSM chat\n"
ECHO OFF
ABORT 'NO DIAL TONE'
ABORT 'NO DIALTONE'
ABORT 'NO ANSWER'
ABORT 'NO CARRIER'
ABORT 'DELAYED'
ABORT 'VOICE'
ABORT 'BUSY'
'' 'AT'
OK 'ATZ'
OK 'AT+CSQ'
OK 'AT+CPIN=****'
# Added the correct pin just above
REPORT CONNECT
OK 'AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","smartsites.t-mobile"'
SAY "Dialing...\n"
OK 'ATD*99#'
SAY "Waiting for CONNECT...\n"
TIMEOUT 120
CONNECT ''
SAY "Connected\n"
```

**Logs:**

```
GSM chat
Dialing...
Waiting for CONNECT...
Connected
chat:  May 08 06:28:47 CONNECT 100000000
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -t 90 -f /etc/ppp/peers/gsm_chat finished (pid 604), status = 0x0
Serial connection established.
using channel 1
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/modem_at0
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth eap> <magic 0x1dabaabe> <pcomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x451d49cd> <pcomp> <accomp>]
sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x0 <accomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <auth eap>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x1dabaabe> <pcomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x451d49cd> <pcomp>]
sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x451d49cd> <pcomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfRej id=0x2 <auth chap MD5>]
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x1dabaabe> <pcomp>]
rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x3 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x1dabaabe> <pcomp>]
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group access
rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2 magic=0x451d49cd]
rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x1 <06caf8ebf2c8971a809509e3f27a368a>, name = "UMTS_CHAP_SRVR"]
sent [CHAP Response id=0x1 <ceb886dabe81e0d6484f903ae4ad2d5d>, name = "tmobile"]
rcvd [CHAP Success id=0x1 ""]
CHAP authentication succeeded
CHAP authentication succeeded
sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 0.0.0.0>]
Hangup (SIGHUP)
Modem hangup
Connection terminated.
```

To see if the issue didn't come from the network provider, I tried with another SIM card (from Vodafone NL), and even after reconfiguration, the connection hanged at the same time. I thus imagine that the issue must come either from the machine, either from my configuration.

Does anyone know where the issue might come from, or how I could investigate this more in detail?

Please let me know if you think any detail could help have a clearer view of the issue!

Comment: We are experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you solve your issue - even if its 2 years ago?